# What to input into table header to import featured images with CSV or XML file?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm using the Really Simple CSV Importer plugin and what to import featured images in bulk for my content items.

I've tried multiple combinations like:

post_image

post-thumnail

What could I put into the table header and then how to format the code for image path?

[image: Featured image header]

Comment: You'll need to ask the developer of the Really Simple CSV plugin, or consult its documentation. Third-party plugins are off topic here.

Comment: Ok thanks , will do